# NodeJS как получить return

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть вот такой код:

```js
var login = function(req){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
      return 'ok';
    });
  }
  
 console.log(login); //Здесь должно вывести OK
```

Как мне получить return из события?

Comment: Впрочем это даже не дуликат, т.к. у вас login это функция которую вы не вызываете, так что ни о каком результате и речи быть не может.

Comment: @Alexey Ten , Сейчас скину другой пример кода. Может там все будет проще.

Comment: @Alexey Ten Вот код.

Comment: Где код? Код должен быть в вопросе

Comment: @Alexey Ten От и так в вопросе!